# Expression Trees in .NET 4.0: Expression.Call fails to find method "get_Item" in type List<T>

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

I'm stuck with the problem below and wondering is someone out there will be able to help. I have added comments to the code to make it self-explanatory but let me know if you need more info or if the problem is unclear.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: I've been asked to summarize the problem in text, so here it goes: under the circumstances described in the code below, Expression.Call(...) throws the following exception: "No method 'get_Item' exists on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'"

I believe the method does exist in the type, as shown here:

`List<double> sampleList = new List<double>();`

`Console.WriteLine(sampleList.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item") == null); // False`

I've also made the title a bit more descriptive; sorry if the initial question was not clear.

```
public class ExpressionExample
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<List<double>, double>> component = u => u[0];
        Console.WriteLine(component.Body.NodeType); // Prints out "Call"
        Console.WriteLine(component.Body); // Prints out "u.get_Item(0)"

        MethodCallExpression copyGetComponent = CopyCallExpression(component.Body as MethodCallExpression);
    }

    public MethodCallExpression CopyCallExpression(MethodCallExpression callExpression)
    {
        if (callExpression == null)
            return null;

        // Some tests
        Console.WriteLine(callExpression.Method.Name); // "get_Item"
        List<double> sampleList = new List<double>();
        Console.WriteLine(sampleList.GetType().GetProperty("get_Item") == null); // True
        Console.WriteLine(sampleList.GetType().GetProperty("Item") == null); // False
        Console.WriteLine(sampleList.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item") == null); // False (1)
        Console.WriteLine(sampleList.GetType().GetMethod("Item") == null); // True            
        Console.WriteLine(sampleList.GetType().FullName == callExpression.Method.DeclaringType.FullName); // True! (2)

        // However...
        Type[] argTypes = (from argument in callExpression.Arguments select argument.Type).ToArray();
        // Next line throws an exception: No method 'get_Item' exists on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'
        return Expression.Call(callExpression.Method.DeclaringType, callExpression.Method.Name, argTypes, callExpression.Arguments.ToArray());

        // How does this come together with items (1) and (2) above?
    }
}
```

Edit: I think I've found a workaround that solves my immediate problem; posting it in case someone else out there is struggling with this:

```
public class ExpressionExample
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<List<double>, double>> invokeProp = u => u[0];

        Console.WriteLine(invokeProp); // u => u.get_Item(0)
        Console.WriteLine(invokeProp.Body); // u.get_Item(0)
        Console.WriteLine(invokeProp.Body.NodeType); // Call

        Expression copyGetComponent = CopyCallExpression(invokeProp.Body as MethodCallExpression);

        LambdaExpression copyInvokeProp = Expression.Lambda(copyGetComponent, invokeProp.Parameters);

        Console.WriteLine(copyInvokeProp); // u => u.Item[0]
        Console.WriteLine(copyInvokeProp.Body); // u.Item[0]
        Console.WriteLine(copyInvokeProp.Body.NodeType); // Index

        // Technically different expressions, but I suppose
        // they should be "functionally equal" though
    }

    public Expression CopyCallExpression(MethodCallExpression callExpression)
    {
        if (callExpression == null)
            return null;

        MethodInfo info = callExpression.Method;

        if (info.Name == "get_Item")
        {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(List<double>).GetProperty("Item");
            return Expression.MakeIndex(callExpression.Object, propInfo, callExpression.Arguments);
        }

        if (info.IsStatic)
            return Expression.Call(info, callExpression.Arguments);

        Type[] argTypes = (from argument in callExpression.Arguments select argument.Type).ToArray();
        return Expression.Call(info.DeclaringType, info.Name, argTypes, callExpression.Arguments.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Can you briefly describe in text what the exact problem is (as opposed to describing it in code comments)? What were you expecting and what were the results?

Comment: Simply put, Expression.Call throws the following exception: "No method 'get_Item' exists on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'". I believe that such method actually does exist in that type.

Comment: I've just added this to the problem description too.

Comment: I think I understand your question better, but I don't know the answer :) Some things to look at: get_Item is a special-name method, which might affect results. There might also be something to do with it being on a generic type. I'm not sure if these are actually related but adding one of these items to your debugger watches and inspecting every little property on the member info might yield some answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overload you use is for static methods only (see documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107.aspx). And "get_Item" is clearly not a static method.
So, you need to use a different method overload. Try this, for example:

```
return Expression.Call(callExpression.Object, callExpression.Method, callExpression.Arguments.ToArray());
```

Comment: It's official: I'm going to add the "beginner" tag to my questions from now on. +1 (and many thanks) for bothering to answer this "duh!" stuff (should've read the docs more carefully before posting to begin with).

Comment: If you ask questions about expression trees, you are definitely not a beginner :-) It is a quite advanced topic.

Comment: @Sasha He *could be* a beginner in Expression Trees ) pleased to see girls on this forum, from Microsoft, and Russians! wah.